# list directories which do not start with

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to echo all directories which do not starts let's say with `a` letter. I write following snippet

```
@echo off

for /d %%g in (*) do (
    echo %%~nxg
)
```

and it prints out all directories. How should I filter out those starts with `a`? I'm trying do something with IF-Statement, but fail miserably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it with an `IF`, try this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /D %%g IN (*) DO (
    SET tmp=%%~nxg
    IF NOT "!tmp:~0,1!"=="a" (
        ECHO %%~nxg
    )
)
```

Comment: I will accept it as soon as I can (time limit, huh?) but thats new for me `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` quite useful feature.

Answer (score 5):

**Output filtering**

```dos
dir /ad /b | findstr /i /v /b "a"
```

List the directories (`/ad`) and pipe (`|`) the output of the command into `findstr`, that will select the lines that does not contain (`/v`) at the beginning (`/b`) the string `"a"`, case insensitive (`/i`)

**Substring**

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    for /d %%a in (*) do (
        set "name=%%~na"
        if /i not "!name:~0,1!"=="a" echo %%a
    )
```

`for` replaceable parameters do not allow the use of substring operations, so a variable is needed. But as the variable is changed inside a block of code (code in parenthesis) and normal variable expansion is done when the block is parsed, not when it is executed, delayed expansion is needed to retrieve (read) the value from the changed variable.

The problem with this code is it will fail when folder's names contain `!` as it will be consumed by the parser in the `set` command. To handle it, delayed expansion should be enabled/disabled when needed

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /d %%a in (*) do (
        set "name=%%~na"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%b in ("!name:~0,1!") do (
            endlocal
            if /i not "%%~b"=="a" echo %%a
        )
    )
```

**Character removal**

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /d %%a in (*) do (
        for /f "tokens=* delims=aA" %%b in ("a%%a") do (
            if /i "%%~b"=="%%~a" echo %%a
        )
    )
```

Here a `for /f` is used, configured to see the letters `aA` as delimiters but to retrieve all the tokens. This will make the `for /f` remove all the delimiters (`aA`) from the start of the line. If the remaining data is equal to the initial data, the name of the folder does not start with `a` or `A`

Answer (score 3):

```
for /d %%g in (*) do (
    for /f "eol=a tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("%%~nxg") do echo %%~fg
)
```